# Database is in use - Cannot connect to the database with my application

Tags: delphi, firebird, simultaneous, ibexpert

I am using Firebird 4.0 with SuperServer installed on Microsoft Windows 2011. I am developing a **win64** database application with Delphi to access the database file on a remote computer.

If I connect to the database file with IBExpert while I also try to connect to the same database with the application I am developing, I get the following error message:

> [FireDAC][Phys][FB]lock time-out on wait transaction
> object D:\MYFILES\DATABASE\SZERYNG\IMOVEIS_FIREBIRD\BANCO DE DADOS\DBIMOVEIS.FDB is in use

I can open more than one IBExpert and connect to the same database file but I cannot connect to the database file with my application if any other application like IBExpert is connected to the same database file.

| IBExpert FDConnection | IBExpert database registration info | My application's FDConnection parameters |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Database Database File | D:\MyFiles\Database\Szeryng\Imoveis_Firebird\Banco de Dados\DBIMOVEIS.FDB | D:\MyFiles\Database\Szeryng\Imoveis_Firebird\Banco de Dados\DBIMOVEIS.FDB |
| Server/Protocol Protocol | Remote, TCP/IP | TCPIP |
| Server Name Server | 127.0.0.1 | 127.0.0.1 |
| Port | 3040 | 3040 |
| User Name User_Name | SYSDBA | SYSDBA |
| Charset Character Set | ISO8859_1 | ISO8859_1 |
| Server Version | Firebird 4.0 |  |
| SQL Dialect |  | 3 |
| Client Library File FDPhysFBDriveLink.VendorLib | c:\windows\syswow64\**fbclient.dll** | c:\windows\system32\**fbclient.dll** |

**IBExpert database registration info:**

```
Database File: D:\MyFiles\Database\Szeryng\Imoveis_Firebird\Banco de Dados\DBIMOVEIS.FDB
Server/Protocol: Remote, TCP/IP
Server Name: 127.0.0.1
Port: 3040
User Name: SYSDBA
Charset: ISO8859_1
Server Version: Firebird 4.0
Client Library File: c:\windows\syswow64\fbclient.dll
```

**My application's FDConnection parameters:**

```
Database: D:\MyFiles\Database\Szeryng\Imoveis_Firebird\Banco de Dados\DBIMOVEIS.FDB;
Protocol: TCPIP;
Server: 127.0.0.1;
Port: 3040;
User_Name: SYSDBA;
Character Set: ISO8859_1;
SQL Dialect: 3;
IBAdvanced: set_db_readonly=0;

FDPhysFBDriveLink.VendorLib = c:\windows\system32\fbclient.dll;
```

My application does not use the embedded Firebird client. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Either your Delphi application is using Firebird Embedded, or your IBExpert sessions are. Since Firebird 3.0, it is actually pretty easy to "accidentally" use Firebird Embedded, by referencing the `fbclient.dll` of your Firebird installation (instead of - for example - the one in the Windows System32/SysWOW64 directory) and using a connection string which only consists of the database filepath or alias (no hostname, or one of the new connection URL prefixes). In any case, you will need to post the exact configuration and connection URL used in both IBExpert and your Delphi application.

Comment: Error is different. "Lock time-out on nowait transaction" instead of "I/O error during CreateFile (open)".

Comment: Problematic attachment options requested exclusive access to database. Such options may be dpb_disable_wal, dpb_set_read_only, dpb_set_db_replica or dropDatabase().

Comment: You are still using 127.0.0.1 (which uses the local loopback engine instead of remote). Did you try your real IP address on the local network (for both programs)?

Comment: @user13964273 Good point, I hadn't double checked the exact error message that happens when you open the file through two different processes.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be caused during attach to a database by Database Parameters Block including one of following options: isc_dpb_disable_wal, isc_dpb_set_read_only or dpb_set_db_replica. Former will throw the error unconditionally the rest only if the connection is not alone.

Also an attempt of dropping of the database with more than one connection will result in this error but I don't think that this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

After I have removed from the **IBAdvanced** parameter of **FDConnection** the **set_db_readonly=0**, now my application can connect to the database while IBExpert or any other application is already connect to the same database.

I have included the **set_db_readonly=0** parameter in the **IBAdvanced** parameter of the **FDConnection** as suggested by the help of FireDAC to set the database as read\write.